# No forward accessible form outside

Tags: ubuntu, port-forwarding, lamp, irc

I've setup a UNIX ubuntu VM with VMWare its running IRC, HTTP, FTP & MySQL, ports are forwarded in the modemrouter (its my home network its running on) but still no result.

Any Idea hwo to fix it?
Note i've been testing with: mibbit.com, http://downformeorjusteveryone.com

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI - Ubuntu is *not* Unix.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ensured that your VM 's NIC is set for bridge networking mode versus the default mode of NAT? You will also need to set up a working static IP for your network and ensure the port forwards are pointing the corresponding application ports to the VM IP.

Comment: Yes I have it to bridged always. In the router the setting is always use the same IP and the ports are linked to the VM's IP in the router

Comment: You might consider verifying that the applications are responsive from within the local network.